# The task is fetch and upload images to my digital ocean space in Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I am using digital ocean to store the images, the data stored is private and i want to fetch these images from the priavte spaces and update the data using flutter.

i tried using all the packages but they are so much confusing and i want to generate the signed url thrugh which i can get the signed url in flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.